# React query shows previous page data in new page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-query

I have a react project including two pages: blog and gallery. I can fetch data with `react-query` and navigate between pages with `react-router`. The problem is when I navigate from blog to gallery (and vice versa), the blog content is shown inside gallery while gallery data is being loaded.

Here is my main `App` function:

```
function App() {
   return (
      <>
         <Helmet
            ...
         ></Helmet>
         <Header />
         <main>
            <Switch>
               <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
               <Route path="/gallery" component={Gallery} />
               <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
               <Route component={Error404} /> */}
            </Switch>
         </main>
         <Footer />
      </>
   );
}

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.render(
   <BrowserRouter>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
         <ScrollToTop />
         <App />
      </QueryClientProvider>
   </BrowserRouter>,
   document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

Here is my Fetch Component:

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "../molecules/Card";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

// function name is different in Gallery Component
export default function BlogCardStack(props) {
   const { isLoading, error, data, isFetching } = useQuery("repoData", () =>
      fetch(props.contentSource).then((res) => res.json(), { keepPreviousData : false }),
   );

   if (error) return "An error has occurred: " + error.message;

   return (
      <div className="card-stack">
         {data
            ? data.map((item) => (
             \\ I use <VideoCard> instead of <Card> in Gallery
                 <Card
                    key={item.id}
                    title={item.title.rendered}
                    image={{
                       src: item.featured_media_src_url,
                    }}
                 />
              ))
            : Array(4)
                 .fill()
                 .map((item, index) => <Card key={index} />)}
         {/* {isFetching ? "Updating..." : ""} */}
         {/* <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen /> */}
      </div>
   );
}
```

I use the code above in both Blog and Gallery components, just by changing the `return` part

## Update

I changed keys but no luck.

Comment: What does the URL look like after you navigate between blog and gallery?

Comment: webistename.com/gallery, websitename.com/blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide a unique queryKey for every data that you want to fetch, otherwise, they will keep overwriting each other. The query cache is like an object where the queryKey is the "key" of that object, and your data is the value.

in your example, it would be best to achieve this by adding `props.contentSource` to the key:

```
const { isLoading, error, data, isFetching } = useQuery(
    ['data', props.contentSource],
    () => fetch(props.contentSource).then((res) => res.json()),
);
```

`keepPreviousData` defaults to `false` so you don't need to set that.